# How does the step "exclude diagonally joint cells" work in Tents and Trees?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I'm trying to learn the logic behind solving Tents and Trees.

I found this interesting tool:

https://g2384.github.io/tents-and-trees-puzzle-solver/

Now I get most of the steps of solving the puzzle - except step 3 "exclude diagonally joint cells" in the 8x8 demo.

How does this step work? How are the tiles selected and how do you know these should be grass?

[image]

Comment: It looks like that step has been reworded. It now says, "exclude open land (no adjacent tree)".

Comment: @LannyStrack; that depends on the grid you are trying to solve - it appears later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solver doesn't show the hints. I've added the relevant hints and marked the cells it excludes.

[image]

If any of the red cells would have a tent, there is not enough room to satisfy the hints in the 1st or 4th row.